# How to get the docker version of the host in the dynamic inventory and/or Ansible facts?

Tags: docker, vmware-vsphere, ansible, ansible-playbook

We would like to do different things on hosts that run Docker 1.12 than on Docker 1.10 in Ansible.

How can I obtain the version of Docker specified in my inventory, so that I can later say...

- Fetch all hosts that run Docker 1.10 on environment Testing and run
  this Ansible playbook.

I don't know if it matters, but we mainly use VMware with CoreOS or CentOS installed on the virtual machines.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example how you could do what you want:

```
---
 - hosts: localhost
   remote_user: test
   tasks:
     - name: get docker version
       shell: "docker -v | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | cut -d ',' -f 1"
       register: version

     - debug: var=version.stdout

     - name: do something if version is 1.13.0
       shell: "echo it is 1.13.0"
       when: version.stdout == "1.13.0"

     - name: do nothing if version is 1.13.0
       shell: "echo nothing"
       when: version.stdout != "1.13.0"
```

You get the docker version and store it in a variable. Then with properly set conditions you can execute the tasks you need to. The output of the test playbook is:

```
[me@mac]$ ansible-playbook test.yml
 [WARNING]: Host file not found: /etc/ansible/hosts

 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available


PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [get docker version] ******************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "version.stdout": "1.13.0"
}

TASK [do something if version is 1.13.0] ***************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [do nothing if version is 1.13.0] *****************************************
skipping: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

I have docker 1.13.0. The playbook was run on my Mac, but it will work on CentOS too. Depending on permissions you might need to use `sudo`. Ansible version in the example is 2.2.1.0, but it will work on lower versions too.

You can run a similar playbook against your inventory, and do `echo $HOSTNAME` for all hosts which have the desired docker version - that way you will gather the information you need. Of course you may omit the output with grep.

Answer (score 2):

This is the approach I chose:

```
    - name: docker server version
      shell: "docker version --format '{{ '{{' }}.Server.Version{{ '}}' }}'" 
      register: docker_server_version
      changed_when: False
```

The *--format* option of the docker-version command allows you to select a json key, in this case I wanted to check the version of the server.

The problem is that the docker-version command requires the use of '{{' and '}}', for you to escape them, one option would be the following:

```
'{{ '{{' }}.Server.Version{{ '}}' }}'
```

This is explained in the jinja2 documentation:
https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#escaping

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

[local_facts](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#local-facts-facts-d) might be an option here:

Create a file  on the target systems `/etc/ansible/facts.d/apps.fact` with content:

```
[docker]
version=1.13.0
```

The variable should than be available in Ansible as `{{ ansible_local.apps.docker.version }}`

You might want to update the facts file with the role used to install docker.